# Jsoup: how to get ID and href within many elements

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup, html-parser

I need to get IDs and href witin all elements (shown in the picture in colored boxes). I don't know how exactly adress the path and extract the required informaton. How can I do this?

[image: HTML Structure]

Answer (score 0):

Select by id and tags till you get to the relevant tags and then get them by attribute. Check the code snippet below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("html_file");

Element loginform = doc.getElementById("search_result_container");
Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("div");
Element secondDiv = inputElements.get(1);
Elements hyperLinks = secondDiv.getElementsByTag("a");

for (Element alink : hyperLinks) {
    String href = alink.attr("href");
    String id = alink.attr("id");            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it. It works!! Thanks to  SUNNYben, you gave me the right input!!!

And here is my Solution-Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Steam_GameID_Links
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Steam_GameID_Links wc = new Steam_GameID_Links();
        try
        {
            String url = "http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=_ASC&category1=998&page=1";
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // nur die Spielnamen
            Elements howMuchPages = document.select(".search_pagination_right");
            String[] stuff = howMuchPages.text().split(" ");
            String tmp = stuff[4].replace(" ", "").replace(".", "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++)
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(tmp.charAt(i)))
                {
                    sb.append(tmp.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            String last = sb.toString().trim();;
            int lastPages = Integer.parseInt(last);
            int counter = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i < lastPages + 1; i++)
            {
                url = "http://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=_ASC&category1=998&page=" + i;
                document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // waehlt zunaechst den ElternKnoten: <div id="search_result_container">
                Element parentNode = document.getElementById("search_result_container");
                Elements childNodes = parentNode.getElementsByAttribute("data-ds-appid");
                for(Element alink : childNodes)
                {
                    String href = alink.attr("href");
                    String id = alink.attr("data-ds-appid");
                    String name = alink.getElementsByClass("title").text();
                    System.out.println("Spiel: " + name + ", ID: " + id + ", SpieleLink: " + href);
                    // wc.writeSpielNameIDLink("Spiel: " + name + ", ID: " + id + ", SpieleLink: " + href + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```